# Transferring projects

Tags: swift2, xcode7, ios9.3

How do I get all my content from the main storyboard of one project to another separate project? I need to transfer the project because strange errors are occurring that go away if I transfer, but I don't want to lose my storyboard content which wasn't a problem to begin with.

Comment: Scott, did you try just copy it? Or grab the source code and to put into the new project?

Comment: I tried replacing the new blank one with the old one and it generated lots of errors so I put the blank one back in. I forgot how to get to the base code but I figure it would probably generate the same errors.

Comment: I tried many times to do it like this. Grab just XML elements that represent all viewcontrollers. Don't take all the code, just those scenes you need. The best would be to try copying scene by scene with checking interface builder if everything is OK. If you would like to, I'll try to help, just send me the code. Unfortunately there isn't more straight way to save time. I wouldn't like to do the same work in IB once again either.

Comment: I have the new project and old one on bithub but it's under a private account. So if you are also on bithub then give me your username and I will include you on the list.